# Kotlin - Destructuring in loops not working - var not accessible

Tags: kotlin

some [background](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html):

```
val (name, age) = person
```

This syntax is called a destructuring declaration. It creates multiple variables (*correction, creates multiple values*) at at the same time.

Destructuring declarations also work in for-loops: when you say:

```
for ((a, b) in collection) { ... }
```

Lets take a look at a list item i have:

```
    @Parcelize
data class MyModel(
        var name: String = "",
        var is_locked: Boolean = true,
        var is_one_size: Boolean = false,
) : Parcelable
```

and now i have obtained a list of "MyModel" classes and i am trying to loop over them like this:

```
private fun initMyModelList(model: MutableList<MyModel>) {
 //i want to access is_locked from here with destruction but i cant ? IDE telling me the type is an int but its clearly defined as a Boolean
        for((is_locked) in model){
          //what i want to do in here is access the is_locked var of the model list and change all of them in a loop. im trying to use Destructuring in loop as a conveience. why is it not working ?
//how can i make the call signature look like this--- > is_locked = true instad of model.is_locked =true 
        }
}
```

all i want to do is be able to call is_locked = true instead of model.is_locked = true within the loop. how can this be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This syntax is called a destructuring declaration. It creates multiple variables at at the same time.

It doesn't create multiple variables, it captures multiple values. You're working with values, not references, as your source tells further:

> A destructuring declaration is compiled down to the following code:
>
> ```
> val name = person.component1()
> val age = person.component2()
> ```

Closest to what you want would be this custom extension function:

```
inline fun <E> Iterable<E>.withEach(block: E.() -> Unit) {
    forEach {
        it.block()
    }
}
```

Use like so:

```
model.withEach {
    is_locked = true
}
```

Before you ask the obligatory question "why isn't this included in stdlib?" consider that functional style programming typically is about transforming *immutable* types. Basically, what I did here was encourage a bad habit.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it isn't possible, cause your code is compiled to something like:

```
for (m in models) {
    val is_locked = m.component1()
    ...
}
```

Which means that you create a local property which cannot be reassigned. But you can do something like this:

```
for (m in model) {
    with(m) {
        is_locked = true
    }
}
```

Yep, it isn't perfect, but it can be improved with extension methods:

```
fun <T> List<T>.forEachApply(block: T.() -> Unit) {
    forEach(block)
}

private fun initMyModelList(model: MutableList<MyModel>) {
    model.forEachApply { 
        is_locked = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice touch with `forEach(block)`. I didn't know that `T.() -> Unit` and `(T) -> Unit` are equal as far as method references are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring in a loop just fine as read-only values.

```
data class Stuff(val name: String, val other: String)

fun doStuff() {
    val stuff = Stuff("happy", "day")
    val stuffs = listOf(stuff)

    for ((name) in stuffs) {
        println(name)
    }
}
```

Running that method prints "happy" to the console. Baeldung shows an example of using it [here](http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-destructuring-declarations).

It's best practice for data classes to be immutable, so I would try to rewrite your data class to be immutable. The `.copy` function will let you copy your data class but with new, different values.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Ah, yeah, my bad. I guess I just assume immutability when working with data classes so thoroughly I glossed over that part!

Comment: Very good info. Yes I found out there read only today. Thanks